# How does order of defining variables affect my program?

Tags: python, pygame

```
import pygame,shooter_f

background_colour = (87, 151, 153)
(width, height) = (1920, 1080)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
pygame.display.set_caption('Shooter 2D Game')
screen.fill(background_colour)


pygame.display.flip()


class player:
    global screen
    def __init__(self,x,y,colour,speed):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.colour = colour
        self.speed = speed
    def move(self):
        global move_ticker
        move_ticker = 0
        self.old_x = self.x
        self.old_y = self.y
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[pygame.K_a]:
            if move_ticker == 0:
                move_ticker = 60
            self.x -= self.speed
        if keys[pygame.K_d]:
            if move_ticker == 0:
                move_ticker = 60
            self.x += self.speed
        if keys[pygame.K_w]:
            if move_ticker == 0:
                move_ticker = 60
            self.y -= self.speed
        if keys[pygame.K_s]:
            if move_ticker == 0:
                move_ticker = 60
            self.y += self.speed
    # def shoot(self):
    #     self.b = bullet(self.x//2,self.y//2,4,self,(0,0,255))

    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen,self.colour,(self.x//2,self.y//2,100,100))
    def update(self):
        self.move()
        pygame.draw.rect(screen,background_colour,(self.old_x//2,self.old_y//2,100,100))
        self.draw()
        # self.shoot()
        # self.b.update()



class bullet():
    global screen,background_colour
    def __init__(self,x,y,velocity,colour):
        self.new_x = x
        self.new_y = y
        self.colour = colour
        self.velocity = velocity

    def draw(self):

        pygame.draw.rect(screen,self.colour,(self.new_x//2,self.new_y//2,33,33))
    def clear_up(self):

        print
        pygame.draw.rect(screen,background_colour,(self.old_x,self.old_y,33,33))
    def update(self):

        self.old_x = self.new_x
        self.old_y = self.new_y
        self.clear_up()
        self.new_x += self.velocity
        self.draw()




shooter_one =player(400,400,(255,255,255),2)
a = bullet(400,400,10,(255,0,0))

running = True
while running:
    shooter_one.update()
    a.update()
    pygame.display.update()
    if move_ticker > 0:
        move_ticker -= 1
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
          running = False
```

Within the bullet class, the clear_up() function acts to draw a square of the same Rect(), with the colour of the background effectively erasing it, this is done through setting old_x to the previous x value and updating this new_x. This method worked in the class before but not in this class? How does the order differ in terms of defintion of old_x and new_x

Comment: For what it's worth, you don't need `old_x` and `old_y` at all in this code, since you're only updating `new_x`/`new_y` *after* `clear_up` has been called. Both `clear_up` and `draw` could work with the same variables!

Answer (score 2):

`draw` draws the bullet at the position (`self.new_x//2`, `self.new_y//2`). Therefore, you must draw the rectangle with the background color at (`self.old_x//2`, `self.old_y//2`) instead of (`self.old_x`, `self.old_y`) in the function `clear_up`:

<s>`pygame.draw.rect(screen,background_colour,(self.old_x,self.old_y,33,33))`</s>

```py
pygame.draw.rect(screen,background_colour,(self.old_x//2,self.old_y//2,33,33))
```

However, I suggest just to use 1 draw method with an `color` argument:

```py
class bullet():
    global screen, background_colour
    def __init__(self, x, y, velocity, colour):
        self.new_x = x
        self.new_y = y
        self.colour = colour
        self.velocity = velocity

    def draw(self, color):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, color, (self.new_x//2, self.new_y//2, 33, 33))
   
    def update(self):
        self.draw(background_colour)
        self.new_x += self.velocity
        self.draw(self.colour)
```